# VBA Object to Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a column with multiple, and sometimes the same, names. I wanted to know the amount of unique names in that list which I managed to know by the following code:

```
Sub vba_string_array()
Dim unique_agents As Long, List As Object, Rng As Range
Set List = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each Rng In Range("F4:F15")
    If Not List.Exists(Rng.Value) Then List.Add Rng.Value, Nothing
Next
unique_agents = List.Count - 1
End sub
```

I got my hands on this code through StackOverflow and if I read it correctly, Object "List" has all the unique names of all the names.

How do I transfer these object to an array?

Comment: You read the help page for the microsoft scripting runtime scripting.dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Keys` function gives the result

```
Sub vba_string_array()
Dim unique_agents As Long, List As Object, Rng As Range
Set List = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each Rng In Range("F4:F15")
    If Not List.Exists(Rng.Value) Then List.Add Rng.Value, Nothing
Next
unique_agents = List.Count - 1
arr = List.Keys                        'added
End sub
```

The arr is an array with index start according to Option Base statement, if not declared then default value is `0`.

Comment: Note null/empty values might/will be included. In some cases might be desirable to include null/empty values.